# Tweak Performance of a Web Page Watcher

Tags: perl, http, curl, grep

I am writing a basic script to watch a web page and interact with it when something changes.

I'm writing in Perl, using curl to get the page and grep to watch it for changes.

The *watch* structure I am using is the following

```
my $string = '';
do {
  $string = curl -s --cookie cookie.txt "http://url.com/resource" | grep "thing_that_has_appeared"
  } until ( $string ne '' );
```

It is then passed into a string which is used to extract info.

The page itself, when downloaded as a file with curl is 16KB.

I am seeing significant load when running this, both on network bandwidth and processor usage.

The point is to watch the page *as closely as possible*, that is on the second or fraction of a second scale, so some reasonable load is acceptable. I was just wondering if I might be going about it wrongly, and if there could be a more efficient way of watching the page?

The server is not issuing a `Last-Modified` header.

Is there any way I could instruct curl (or interrupt it maybe) to stop downloading the page once I have confirmed it has not changed?

I think mostly I need insight here. Mine is too limited.

Edit: in response to comment I have included the loop, and specified time span.

Comment: The curl command fetches the web page just once. If you are seeing *significant load* then you must have wrapped this command in a loop that you don't show. Please show the rest of your code. What sort of response time are you hoping for with this? Can you check for changes, say, once a day? The best way to do this would be by examining the HTTP header. Are you sure that a change won't be reflected in the headers?

Comment: "Is there any way I could instruct curl (or interrupt it maybe?) to stop downloading the page once I have confirmed it has not changed?" Without a  header like Last-Modified, you can't confirm that the page is the same unless you download the entire thing. (What if only the very last byte had changed?)

Comment: What is `"thing_that_has_appeared"`? It sounds like you're really waiting for specific content rather than a simple change

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Well, knowing the page structure, and which part I want to watch for changes, and assuming it is not the last byte, I guess what I am asking is if there is a way to ignore the part _after_ what I am watching...

Comment: @Borodin Exactly. The page is a list. I am doing : if the list is empty do nothing, once something appears in the list then do stuff. The grep is for what I am waiting for in the list, which is specific, at least in the html markup.

Comment: This is becoming tiresome. We can't tease the real question from you comment by comment. Please ask a proper question

Comment: With [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#ua-get-url), you can specify a callback that is called after every N bytes have been downloaded. If you find the content you're looking for, you can cancel the request partway through.

Comment: @Borodin I'm sorry if I haven't been giving enough context. I was just trying to narrow the scope of the question down. I agree I did not ask very well at first, but I am a new user on Stackoverflow and am not very well informed of the best way to ask questions. If you want my entire code and the website I'm happy to provide it, but I just thought that was too specific if asked that way. Again, sorry if I have annoyed you...

Answer (score 1):

ThisSuitIsBlackNot's answer helped :

> With LWP::UserAgent, you can specify a callback that is called after every N bytes have been downloaded. If you find the content you're looking for, you can cancel the request partway through.

He also references [this](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#ua-get-url) page on metacpan related to the libwww-perl library's Web User Agent.

Thank you for your input.
And again, sorry if the manner of asking the question was inadequate.